# WINAPI Cpp - OpenFileMapping fails with error (2) ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shared-memory, file-mapping

I'm trying to use WinApi to CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile and CopyMemory. It's not showhing me errors and buffor is being filed with my PID

```
int write_pid_to_memory(const char *t_pid)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("[write_pid_to_memory] t_pid: (%s).\n"), t_pid);

    HANDLE h_map_file;
    LPCTSTR p_buf;

    h_map_file = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, // use paging file
        NULL,                 // default security
        PAGE_READWRITE,       // read/write access
        0,                    // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
        BUF_SIZE,             // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
        t_name);              // name of mapping object

    if (h_map_file == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[write_pid_to_memory] Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
                 GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    p_buf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(
        h_map_file,          // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    if (p_buf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[write_pid_to_memory] Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
                 GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(h_map_file);

        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "[write_pid_to_memory] strlen(t_pid) * sizeof(char) " << strlen(t_pid) * sizeof(char) << std::endl;

    CopyMemory((PVOID)p_buf, t_pid, (strlen(t_pid) * sizeof(char)));

    _getch();

    std::cout << "p_buf " << p_buf << std::endl;

    UnmapViewOfFile(p_buf);

    CloseHandle(h_map_file);

    return 0;
}
```

... but then there is reading from memmory

```
int access_pid_from_memory()
{

    HANDLE h_map_file;
    LPCTSTR p_buf;

    h_map_file = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write access
        FALSE,               // do not inherit the name
        t_name);             // name of mapping object

    if (h_map_file == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[access_pid_from_memory] Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
                 GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    p_buf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(
        h_map_file,          // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    if (p_buf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[access_pid_from_memory] Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
                 GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(h_map_file);

        return 1;
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, p_buf, TEXT("[access_pid_from_memory] Process2"), MB_OK);

    UnmapViewOfFile(p_buf);

    CloseHandle(h_map_file);

    return 0;
}
```

where I get System Error (2) while trying to open Mapping.

```
My PID: 19516
[access_pid_from_memory] Could not open file mapping object (2).
[write_pid_to_memory] t_pid: (19516).
[write_pid_to_memory] strlen(t_pid) * sizeof(char) 5
p_buf 19516
Envariamental variable = NEW
Env var value length = 3
Env var value compare resault = 0
Mutex created sucesfully
```

Code of those functions is from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory
and only thing I've changed is

```
CopyMemory((PVOID)p_buf, t_pid, (strlen(t_pid) * sizeof(char)));
```

Instead of

```
CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
```

Where t_pid is just a const char *, becouse I was tired of Windows TCHAR types and I had no clue how to convert DWORD ProcessID to TCHAR to pass it to memcopy.

Well, I'm clueless why I'm unable to open Mapping. Windows is probably beyond me and I have no idea
how

```
TCHAR t_name[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
```

is supposed to be recognised by system to find memory from which I want to read a message.


Whole programm is supposed to lock execution for only one process and if there is a System variable named "SO2" of value "NEW", new process should stop execution of previous process and continoue locking program for himself.

Locking mechanism is with mutex and to find previous porcess ID, I wanted my current process ID to be saved in memory, for next process to read it form, to close it when sys var will be "NEW". 
Nothing crazy. All of this in Linux I've done in one day, but Windows is killing me.

Please help

There is main if someone would be intrested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048
#define ENV_KEY "SO2"
#define ENV_VAL "NEW"

#define BUF_SIZE 256

TCHAR t_name[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
HANDLE h_mutex;

int write_pid_to_memory(const char *dw_pid);
int access_pid_from_memory();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    DWORD dw_pid = GetCurrentProcessId();

    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << dw_pid;
    const char *t_pid = stream.str().c_str();

    // int legnth = s_pid.length()
    // const char *t_pid = (char*)malloc( * sizeof(char));

    // const char t_pid = (char)malloc(strlen(dw_pid) * sizeof(char));

    std::cout << "My PID: " << dw_pid << std::endl;

    access_pid_from_memory();
    write_pid_to_memory(t_pid);

    std::string env_val(ENV_VAL);
    char c_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    LPCSTR lp_name = ENV_KEY;
    LPSTR lp_buffer = c_buffer;
    DWORD dw_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
    DWORD get_env_var;

    //Write to memory your pid for other process to access it and close you

    get_env_var = GetEnvironmentVariable(
        lp_name,
        lp_buffer,
        dw_size);

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't find envariamental variable \"SO2\"." << std::endl;
    }

    if (BUFFER_SIZE == get_env_var)
    {
        std::cout << "Buffer for function [GetEnvironmentVariable] is too small. Function failed." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Envariamental variable = " << lp_buffer << std::endl;
    std::string str_buffer(lp_buffer);
    std::cout << "Env var value length = " << str_buffer.length() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Env var value compare resault = " << str_buffer.compare(env_val) << std::endl;

    HANDLE h_mutex = NULL;

    LPCSTR str = ENV_KEY;

    h_mutex = OpenMutex(
        MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,
        TRUE,
        str);

    if (NULL != h_mutex)
    {
        if (str_buffer.compare(env_val) == 0)
        {
            //Realease mutex3
            ReleaseMutex(h_mutex);
            //Close previous process
        }
        else
        {

            throw std::runtime_error("Instance of a program is already running");
        }
    }

    h_mutex = CreateMutex(
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        str);

    if (h_mutex == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create mutex: error - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Mutex created sucesfully" << std::endl;

    DWORD dw_wait_res;

    dw_wait_res = WaitForSingleObject(
        h_mutex,   // handle to mutex
        INFINITE); // no time-out interval

    for (;;)
    {
        Sleep(100);
    }

    CloseHandle(h_mutex);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the openfilemapping is supposed to be in one program and the createfilemapping in a different one. The create is called first then open is called by the other process. Even if all one process you have to call create first

Comment: @pm100 Well, I'm running two instances of a programm, so there are two programms. First I need to read the PID and then I decide if I want to continue with execution

Comment: error code say to you that not exist section with this name, whhen you try open it

Comment: @pm100 and I know I have to create first but I'm expected to run the same code in diffrent processes, so first, I need to check if there is already memmory with PID and if not, I need to create one. I was changing the order in which both function are called but effect was the same

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I know that but there is no reason for code to not find this Shared Named Memory. At least I can't see the reason

Comment: can be 3 reasons - you use different names, you yet not create section, you already close section

Comment: @RbMm 
1. Name is from global variable.
2. There is no errors when creating section and buffer is being filed with content to store.
3. I was trying to not UnmapViewOfFile and was using create function before opening it (still, I'm creating two processes with the same code, so it shouldn't matter)

Idk how but windows just doesn't like me

Comment: again - how about variant - you close section before try open it in another process ?

Comment: @RbMm Aparently yes, I've commented out UnmapViewOfFile in read function, and it worked

Comment: no, not `UnmapViewOfFile` but `CloseHandle(h_map_file);`

Comment: @RbMm It's only a handle. Each function creates it's own handle and is done with it at the end when it stoped reading or writing. What is freeing space in memory is Unmap function. I need to time this right in program

Comment: when last handle on named object is closed and object have not permanent flag - name of object is destroyed. when you close section ( CloseHandle(h_map_file); ) - it have no more name

Comment: @RbMm You're right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logging clearly shows `[access_pid_from_memory]` occurs *before* `[write_pid_to_memory]`.

And we can clearly see in your `main()` function that it calls `access_pid_from_memory()` first (which attempts to open the memory map and then closes it), and then afterwards calls `write_pid_to_memory()` (which creates the memory map and then closes it).  Since there is no active handle referring to the mapping, it gets destroyed as soon as `write_pid_to_memory()` exits.

So, you are doing operations **out of order**, which is why `OpenFileMapping()` is failing.  At no point does the mapping actually exist when `access_pid_from_memory()` is trying to open it.

You need to do the following instead:

- in one process, *create* the mapping first, **and leave it open**.
- THEN, in another process, open the mapping **while it is still open in the previous process**.
- THEN, use the mapped memory as needed.
- THEN, close the mapping in both processes.

There are other issues with your code, too:

- converting the process ID to a string just to share it.  You can share the ID as a binary `DWORD` instead.
- `access_pid_from_memory()` doesn't actually read anything from the mapping (if it were able to open it at all).
- `main()` is assigning `t_pid` to point at *dangling memory*.  The call to `stream.str()` produces a *temporary* `std::string` that is destroyed as soon as `c_str()` exits.
- I don't even know what you are attempting to do with your environment variable and mutex, and what that has to do with sharing memory.  For purposes of this post, you should remove that code until you have your shared memory working properly.

Comment: Thank you for your insides. I'm explaining reason for the main feature of program before showing main() in my post. I started writing program with locking mechanism and tried to adapt Microsoft example to my case. Whole thing isn't finished yet, that's why function reading memory doesn't have buffer to write to. It's something I'm working on right now. What I need is to sort out my handle to mapping usage; I didn't know about object destruction when there is no handle left - Thank you for the help.

Comment: @BartłomiejBłaszczyk "*Thank you for your insides*" - I think you mean **insights**. You don't want my *insides* ;-)

Comment: - converting the process ID to a string just to share it. You can share the ID as a binary DWORD instead. <br/>
How would you do that?

Comment: @BartłomiejBłaszczyk Simply allocate the shared memory to `sizeof(DWORD)` number of bytes, get a `DWORD*` pointer to the memory, and then assign the original process ID `DWORD` to that memory.